# Links to Wordpress shop from Drupal menu add Base URL twice

Tags: navigation

I'm working on a site that has the main site built in Drupal and the shop is built in Wordpress/Woocommerce (messy I know - not my choice).

The problem is that when I link to a product in wordpress from the Drupal main menu, it adds the base URL twice. For example, the URL should be http://www.example.com/shop/product but when I try to add the link Drupal creates it as www.example.com/http://www.example.com/shop/product

I have tried to use the relative URL instead, but Drupal won't let me.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! In which way do you create the links to the products? Did you try using absolute URLs?

Comment: Yes, I have tried using both absolute and relative URLs. The absolute URLs cause the problems that I mentioned above and the relative ones were not accepted by Drupal so I could not use them.